# Vibration for LG Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, 4.2-jelly-bean, vibration, lg-optimus-l3

I don't know about the other models, but my LG Optimus L3 2 doesn't vibrate while touching the virtual keyboard. That's really bad, because it's annoying to hear a sound to make sure the key was pressed. Since I couldn't find any option to activate that, I tried another keyboard available in market and it worked, but I still don't have vibration while pressing the return key. Is there a way to activate vibration for all keys in the device?

Comment: I was somehow happy my LG does not vibrate on "keypresses" -- but allright, it should be configurable as tastes differ. Have you checked the settings for "haptic feedback", and played with what you've found?

Comment: I can't find such options. Where are they in your phone?

Comment: I didn't check in my O4X (felt no need yet), but remember having seem them. I admit it might have been in CyanogenMod on one of my other devices. // Just checked: Yes, I have a corresponding setting in *Settings->Sound*, rawly translating to "sound when typing*. Maybe you check that section?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Go Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gokeyboard)?

I use Go Keyboard on Samsung Galaxy S4. It vibrates when I press the return key. It's customizable via `Sound and vibrate > Key press vibrate`. You might also want to check `Advanced Setting > Smiley Setting`; this lets you merge the Smiley and the return key function.